# GIT Review:Raise a dependent review on another ongoing review

Tags: java, git, jenkins, gerrit

I have an ongoing gerrit code review say A, now I want to use some code that is part of another ongoing review B that is still not pushed into the code base, can I somehow integrate the code from review B into my work space and make my changes and add that to my existing code review A.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment whether you should do it or not, although it is possible, but, it requires you to be cognizant of what changes go where and actively make sure each branch is up to date with the code base it is tracking.

let's say patchset A has interface classes and patchset B has its implementation.

- create branch Uno for A

  > $ git checkout -b Uno
- set branch Uno to track master repo

  > $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master Uno
- create branch Duo for B

  > $ git checkout -b Duo
- set branch Duo to track Uno

  > $ git branch --set-upstream-to=Uno Duo

By doing so, you have a separate branch for A and a separate branch for B, and you will see code changes from Uno in Duo.

Do remeber to do **git pull --rebase** on Uno and then do the same on Duo to keep all branches updated.

Any changes made in Uno can be pulled into Duo, as the later is tracking the former.

If you want to raise a review on Duo, simple insert the **Depends-on:** tag followed by the commit ID from Uno. This will reflect in review and rebase the patchset raised for Uno.

To read more on the **Depends-on:** tag
https://www.redhat.com/archives/softwarefactory-dev/2016-February/msg00002.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can... but you shouldn't. It's better to wait for change B to be submitted before use it in your work.

If you really want to use a open change in your work, then:

1. Cherry pick the change using the command in Download > Cherry Pick menu in the change screen. Important: add a "-n" parameter in the "git cherry-pick" command so cherry-pick will NOT create a new commit
2. Commit manually using "git commit --amend"
3. Push the patchset 2 of your change to Gerrit

Remember that if change B is changed during review process you'll need to modify change A accordingly.